# Patindex in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, patindex

I am trying to use the `PATINDEX` function in SQL Server 2008 R2 to extract the value 3 from the string

```
Charged Hourly Fee for 3 CR for BCP202DL Personal Development II
```

but I seem to be making a mistake.

I tried

```
SELECT PatIndex('%[0-9]%', 'Charged Hourly Fee for 3 CR for BCP202DL Personal Development II')
```

which returns the position `24` yet I want the value `3`.

Could someone assist with the solution?

Comment: Could you please post your own take on the problem? It'd be easier to point out your mistake.

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Comment: I tried "SELECT PatIndex('%[0-9]%', 'Charged Hourly Fee for 3 CR for BCP202DL Personal Development II')" which returns 24 yet I want the value 3?

Comment: `24` is the **position** of the number `3`. You need to take a look at `SUBSTRING`, and pass the position found with `PATINDEX`. You're almost there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
Select substring(Data, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', Data), 1)
from(
    select 'Charged Hourly Fee for 3 CR for BCP202DL Personal Development II' as Data
)x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the patindex function and the description of your item will never contain another number such as "3" you can use the following:

```
select patindex('%3%', 'Charged Hourly Fee for 3 CR for BCP202DL Personal Development II')
```

This will return 24.

I suspect that you are looking at a string where the quantity ordered is always in the same position. In that case, I would use the substring function.

Comment: Thanks. However this returns the position 24 as you mentioned yet I want to extract the value "3". The value is not always "3" but it always appears in that position. How can I achieve this? Maybe I need not to use patindex?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @str nvarchar (max)
set @str='Charged Hourly Fee for 3 CR for BCP202DL Personal Development II'
Select substring(@str, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', @str), 1)
```

this will return first digit in the string.

The way you were doing was returning the position of the first digit, and my code will return value at that position.